# Is there a reference that lists the correspondence between Glassfish modules and Maven dependency declaration?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am new to Glassfish and Java EE. One thing I find difficult is to connect the modules under the folder `${some-path}/glassfish/modules` to their Maven dependency declaration. For example, this file `javax.persistence.jar` is under `${some-path}/glassfish/modules`. However, how can I know its groupId, artifactId, and its purpose, such as JPA APIs or JPA implementation, etc., so that I know how to use it in a pom.xml?

BTW, I am using Glassfish 4, and Java EE 7.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add these APIs as "provided" dependencies in your pom.xml.

Provided scope means you will have something to compile against, but runtime your application Server (glassfish) will provide an implementation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

or just for jpa stuff:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>  
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Find the full list at this [link](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Java+EE+7+Maven+Coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

The complete set of Maven dependencies for Java EE 7 are described at:

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Java+EE+7+Maven+Coordinates

Alternatively, you can also look at:

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.pom

for the pom that builds GlassFish 4 Java EE 7 Full Platform, or:

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/javaee-web-api/7.0/javaee-web-api-7.0.pom

for the Web Profile.